# Inserting a data in SQL database on ASP.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database

I am working with ASP.NET and using C# to build a website project. I am having problem with connecting to database(inserting)/SQL database while making a register and login form.

I am giving my code below:

Register form:

```
<div id="Sign_Up_Form" style="display: none">
    <form class="modal-content animate" method="post" action="">           
        <div class="input">
                <div>
                    <div>Name</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="First_Name" runat="server" placeholder="First Name" style="height: 20px; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Last_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" style="height: 20px; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Email</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Regi_Email" runat="server" placeholder="Your email here"  style="height: 20px;  width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Password</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Regi_Password" type="password" runat="server" placeholder="**********" style="height: 20px;  width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Confirm Password</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Confirm_Regi_Password" type="password" runat="server" placeholder="**********" style="height: 20px;  width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Age</div>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Age" type="number" runat="server" placeholder="e.g. 21" style="height: 20px;  width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Gender:</div>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="radio" ID="Gender" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Female</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Other</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </br>
                </div>
           </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Register_Button" runat="server" value="Join" OnClick="userRegister" CssClass="button_join" Text="Join" />
    </form>
```

I am not sure if I should give the post method here in the form tags.

The userRegister method is (The edited one, after I got suggestions):

```
  protected void userRegister(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Khulna_website"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
     con.Open();

     string insertQuery = "insert into dbo.users(user_f_name,user_l_name,user_password,user_email,user_age, user_gender) values (@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Regi_Password, @Regi_Email, @Age, @Gender);";

     SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();

     com.CommandText= insertQuery;
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Password", Regi_Password.Text);
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Email", Regi_Email.Text);
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age.Text);
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", First_Name.Text);


     com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();

     Response.Write("Registration is Successful!");     
}
```

My database table code is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users] (
[user_id]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[user_f_name]     VARCHAR (15)  NOT NULL,
[user_l_name]     VARCHAR (15)  NOT NULL,
[user_password]   VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
[user_email]      VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
[user_age]        INT           NOT NULL,
[user_gender]     INT           NOT NULL,
[user_profession] VARCHAR (20)  NULL,
[user_about]      VARCHAR (200) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([user_email] ASC)
);
```

Fact#1 I created the database with add new item-> SQL database. It is created under AppData. Then I again inserted a connectionString under Web.config file. When I fill up the form and submit it, then I see the green color of the connection beside my database (naming dabase.mdf) is gone, and it is red, and I need to refresh it to be green again.

Fact#2 I tried to write the response.write() code in the beginning at the start. But there was no change.

Problem is: Data is not getting inserted. Is either of the facts the reason? Or is there any other problem here that I am missing out?

P.S. I am completely new on this topic and any help is highly appreciated.

edit: I actually have one problem with two facts.. I found out the facts while I was trying to see the root of the problem.

Comment: Please note that on Stack Overflow you should ask only one thing per Question. Someone who knows the answer to one part might not know the answer to another part. Then they may not answer or may not get the credit they deserve for their time and trouble for what they do answer. You can use the [edit] link to fix up your question so that it is only one topic and clear. You're very welcome to open a second Question for your other problem.

Comment: You’re not executing the sql command you build up.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually  I have only one problem, that data were not inserted. I found out two facts that I am anticipating to be a cause of that problem. I edited as you suggested :)

Comment: @TZHX Inside the method? I knew only this way. Should I execute it explicitly again? Or is it the problem that I did not commit?

Comment: You need something like `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` at the end of the method to actually send the command to the database.

Comment: I added just now.. Still not working.

Comment: You have not assigned the connection to the command. You should be getting an Exception and it is customary to include that exception detail in your question.

Comment: I did not get it.. As I said, I am quite new in this. Are you saying I would get an exception, and I should add try/catch block? How to assign the connection to the command?

Comment: should I use using()?

Comment: Yes, you should dispose the resources but that is not why the code is failing. I like to use this sytax (it is not the only way) `SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();`, then set the `CommandText` property of the command.

Comment: You should using blocks around your IDisposable objects, but that's not the cause of your problem. The problem is that you didn't assign the connection to the command. Check for the other constructor overloads of a SqlCommand, some of them take a SqlConnection as a parameter. Use one of those. You should also figure out why you didn't actually see the exception.

Comment: @JigJagJoe if you want someone to know you are talking to them you must address them with @ + username.

Comment: @Crowcoder Okay, I will. And, is the command type text here? I am not using stored procedure here.

Comment: @mason I changed it and used using.. I don't get exception block still, and data is not yet inserted

Comment: I edited accordingly, and editing the edited code into the actual post

Comment: @JigJagJoe `CommandType` is `Text` by default. Get used to [reading documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) to see what properties and methods are available.

Comment: @JigJagJoe Parameter names are case sensitive. `First_name` is different than `First_Name`. Again there should be an exception.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks, I read the documentation, the procedure is clearer to me. And I added that accordingly. Though it's not still working. I am not understanding IDisposable objects. I googled, and as far I saw it is for unmanagable resources. But I am getting confused with all of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `web.config`, your connection string should be something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Khulna_website" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**WebForm:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="input">
        <div>
            <div>Name</div>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="First_Name" runat="server" placeholder="First Name" Style="height: 20px; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Last_Name" runat="server" placeholder="Last Name" Style="height: 20px; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Email</div>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Regi_Email" runat="server" placeholder="Your email here" Style="height: 20px; width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Password</div>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Regi_Password" type="password" runat="server" placeholder="**********" Style="height: 20px; width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Confirm Password</div>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Confirm_Regi_Password" type="password" runat="server" placeholder="**********" Style="height: 20px; width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Age</div>
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="signUp_input" ID="Age" type="number" runat="server" placeholder="e.g. 21" Style="height: 20px; width: 70%; padding-left: 1px;"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Gender:</div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="radio" ID="Gender" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Male</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Female</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Other</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Register_Button" runat="server" value="Join" OnClick="userRegister" CssClass="button_join" Text="Join" />
</form>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void userRegister(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Khulna_website"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string insertQuery = "insert into dbo.users(user_f_name,user_l_name,user_password,user_email,user_age, user_gender) values (@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Regi_Password, @Regi_Email, @Age, @Gender);";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

        connection.Open();

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Password", Regi_Password.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Email", Regi_Email.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender.SelectedValue);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }            
}
```

It should work.

Comment: my web.config file is <connectionStrings>
      <add name="Khulna_website"
       connectionString= "Server=(localDB)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI; Database=Database.mdf;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: If I give runat: server at form it says, it cannot have to runats on same form

Comment: I am even doubting that if it is even entering the method. If it did, at least it would respond "Registration is successful"

Comment: @JigJagJoe Please, replace "Database=Database.mdf" with "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf" in your connection string (without the quotes). Please, add a new WebForm to your project and copy and paste the code from my answer. Run and then open the database table to confirm data have been inserted. If everything works fine, go back to your original WebForm and make sure you have only one form tag with "runat=server" and you have the code I provided in your "userRegister" button event handler. Take *ONE* step at a time to rule errors out.

Comment: I should change attach db filename write? database1 would be database, that's what I know, should I change the data directory too?

Comment: @JigJagJoe If the name of the .mdf file in the App_Data folder is "database1.mdf" then your localdb connection string should contain: "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|database1.mdf". |DataDirectory| is special syntax pointing to the App_Data folder of your project.

Comment: I don't know what's happening.. It's giving this error:  CS1061: 'ASP.default2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'userRegister' and no extension method 'userRegister' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default2_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JigJagJoe make sure the name of the *OnClick* event in the webform matches the name of the event handler method in the code behind.

Comment: I did, now it's making problem in com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", First_Name.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", Last_Name.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Password", Regi_Password.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Regi_Email", Regi_Email.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Age.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender.SelectedValue);...

Comment: can it be a case, the bug is in the software itself?

Comment: @JigJagJoe Please, be specific about errors and error messages. Report the exact error message, at least.

Comment: Finally I could run it, and it said- A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)

Comment: @JigJagJoe Check what localdb instances exist in your system by opening a command prompt and entering the command *sqllocaldb i*. Then check which instance is running by entering the command *sqllocaldb i v11.0* or *sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB*.

Comment: Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#B83F9492\tsql\query are you asking this information?

Comment: @JigJagJoe this is the pipe name. what is the instance name (see the first line)?

Comment: Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.2100.60
Shared name:
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    21-Apr-18 10:10:02 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#B83F9492\tsql\query

Comment: @JigJagJoe Correct. Based on your connection string it should work. I believe it will once you fix the connection issue. Please, read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @JigJagJoe Why don't you revert your connection string from *AttachDBFilename=...* to *Database=...* (as it was originally) and give it a try? Maybe my connection string suggestion doesn't suit your setup (what version of Visual Studio are you running?)

Comment: I think the problem was when I changed the connection string, I changed all of it. That is, I changed the (localdb)v11.0 to (localdb)MSSqlLocalDB... now I took it to original. Is it case sensitive, that it should be localdb, but I gave LocalDB.. Changing that is hard on properties

Comment: @JigJagJoe Your localdb instance is *v11.0* not *MSSQLLocalDB*. Once you have a correct connection string everything else will work, undoubtedly. That's all folks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and patience.. I will notify when I solve the issue

Comment: It's working.. the problem was: it would be (LocalDB not localDB) :D